# Relay Connection

Tags: relay

I am connecting a relay, but I am a bit confused by the datasheet..

Relay:
TE Connectivity Potter & Brumfield Relays RZ03-1A4-D005
Digi-Key: 
PB1267-ND

Datasheet:
http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=RZ&DocType=DS&DocLang=English

This is how I connected it:

[image]

Is it properly connected? Will it be NO?

Comment: How can we tell if it's properly connected when you haven't shown us any context in the schematic (what's it connected to?) and you haven't explained what it's supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your given product code and the datasheet your connection is correct.

[image]

It will be a NO relay where pins A1 and A2 correspond to the coil and pins 11x and 14x are open when coil is off and closed when coil is on.

Comment: Note that the diagram given by the datasheet and OP's part number does not correspond to OP's schematic symbol, so something may be amiss.

Comment: As a schematic symbol you're right, it's different, but the supplier uses the same package (8 pin) for a NO relay (RZ03-1A) and a NO-NC relay (RZ03-1C), given that, pins 121 and 122 would be present in his relay but won't be used.

Comment: Good catch, looks OK then!

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and reply! I made the library for the relay myself, figured it was 8 pins on the relay even though it looks different from the above datasheet-image.

Once again, thanks!